# Where is the Syntax Error in my AWS Terraform declared JSON?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I can Terraform Plan the below with zero issues:

```
resource "aws_iam_group_policy" "devops-admin-write" {
  group = data.aws_iam_group.devops-admin-group.group_name
  policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2020-10-21",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname",
        "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}
```

...but when I Terraform Apply, I get this: "*Error: Error putting IAM group policy terraform-20201022014517696700000001: MalformedPolicyDocument: Syntax errors in policy.
status code: 400, request id: d531aabd-839a-4ebb-9813-b37d7dcad21a"*

The syntax error is apparently in the policy itself, I think. But I can't locate it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [IAM policy version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_version.html) should be:

```
"Version": "2012-10-17"
```

rather then

```
"Version": "2020-10-21"
```

Comment: Wow, OK. I'm an idiot. In my defense, quite the coincidence - I started learning this aspect of Terraform for the first time 4 days ago - on 10/17/2020. When building this in AWS and copying the JSON, I guess I figured it was a date that was reflecting some weird timing quirk. Thanks!